# How Can I Uncomment this line

Tags: html

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    window.sib = { equeue: [], client_key: "" };
    /* OPTIONAL: email to identify request*/
    // window.sib.email_id = 'example@domain.com';
    /* OPTIONAL: to hide the chat on your script uncomment this line (0 = chat hidden; 1 = display chat) */
    // window.sib.display_chat = 0;
    // window.sib.display_logo = 0;
    /* OPTIONAL: to overwrite the default welcome message uncomment this line*/
    // window.sib.custom_welcome_message = 'Hello, how can we help you?';
    /* OPTIONAL: to overwrite the default offline message uncomment this line*/
    // window.sib.custom_offline_message = 'We are currently offline. In order to answer you, please indicate your email in your messages.';
    window.sendinblue = {}; for (var j = ['track', 'identify', 'trackLink', 'page'], i = 0; i < j.length; i++) { (function(k) { window.sendinblue[k] = function(){ var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); (window.sib[k] || function() { var t = {}; t[k] = arg; window.sib.equeue.push(t);})(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2]);};})(j[i]);}var n = document.createElement("script"),i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; n.type = "text/javascript", n.id = "sendinblue-js", n.async = !0, n.src = "https://sibautomation.com/sa.js?key=" + window.sib.client_key, i.parentNode.insertBefore(n, i), window.sendinblue.page();
  })();
</script>
```

I tried searched everywhere and I found <!-- -- > to uncomment it. But when i added <!-- -- > doesn't work in this line. Can anyone help me?

```html
/* OPTIONAL: to overwrite the default offline message uncomment this line*/
```

Comment: That's not HTML. That's JavaScript. Perhaps you should [learn about comments in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comments.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    window.sib = { equeue: [], client_key: "" };
    /* OPTIONAL: email to identify request*/
    // window.sib.email_id = 'example@domain.com';
    /* OPTIONAL: to hide the chat on your script uncomment this line (0 = chat hidden; 1 = display chat) */
    // window.sib.display_chat = 0;
    // window.sib.display_logo = 0;
    /* OPTIONAL: to overwrite the default welcome message uncomment this line*/
    // window.sib.custom_welcome_message = 'Hello, how can we help you?';
    /* OPTIONAL: to overwrite the default offline message uncomment this line*/
    window.sib.custom_offline_message = 'We are currently offline. In order to answer you, please indicate your email in your messages.';
    window.sendinblue = {}; for (var j = ['track', 'identify', 'trackLink', 'page'], i = 0; i < j.length; i++) { (function(k) { window.sendinblue[k] = function(){ var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); (window.sib[k] || function() { var t = {}; t[k] = arg; window.sib.equeue.push(t);})(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2]);};})(j[i]);}var n = document.createElement("script"),i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; n.type = "text/javascript", n.id = "sendinblue-js", n.async = !0, n.src = "https://sibautomation.com/sa.js?key=" + window.sib.client_key, i.parentNode.insertBefore(n, i), window.sendinblue.page();
  })();
</script>
```

In JavaScript, single line comments are indicated by '//', so you want to remove the leading '//' in the line BELOW the instructions. Multi-line comments are indicated with '/*' and '*/' (which are the instructions in this code snippet)